# Can't Open PDF In Firebase Storage

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I am using a FireBase Extension (PDFPlum) to capture the contents of new documents and convert them to a PDF file that is placed in a storage bucket. The process seems to be working, except for the fact that I am unable to download the file. Please see the screenshot below.

[image: Firebase PDF unable to open/view]

Comment: What's the problem in the screenshot? If the problem isn't in the screenshot, edit your question to show the problem.

Comment: I am unable to view the PDF itself. Typically, files in Firebase Storage will download for me when I click on them @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 0):

I think a file is only downloadable from the Firebase console by clicking on its name when a download URL exists for that file, and it sounds like the way you upload them doesn't create a download URL.

You'll want to check if the extension you use has an option to generate a download URL, or maybe file a feature request for it to (optionally) do so.